# Error while passing params in axios with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying a GET request with Axios by passing certain params as follows,

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios
      .get(config.App_URL.getAllMock, {
        params: {
          customHostName: customerData,
          type: "mock",
        },
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Error in fetching the data ${error}`);
      });
    let list = [response.data.routeManager];
    setData(list);
    setLoading(true);
  };
```

`customerData` is fetched from another object passed via contextAPI to this component.

```js
 const [options, setOptions] = useContext(CustomerContext);
```

And then it is mapped as follows,

```js
const hostNames = [];
  options.map((name, index) => {
    hostNames.push(name.customer.customHostName);
  });
  const customerData = hostNames[0];
```

The request is failed with `404` since the `customerData` is not getting passed as a parameter into the payload.
So when i checked the log url is like this,

```
htts://abc.com/v1/route/getAllRoutes?type=mock 404
```

I tried to log the value of `customerData` then in that case I can see the expected value to be passed.
Any idea on how to pass the `customHostName` as param into the payload?

Updated the questions with component I'm referring to,

```js
const MainContent = () => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useContext(CustomerContext);

  const hostNames = [];
  options.map((name, index) => {
    hostNames.push(name.customer.customHostName);
  });
  const customerData = hostNames[0];

  // Get all the mock
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios
      .get(config.App_URL.getAllMock, {
        params: {
          customHostName: customerData,
          type: "mock",
        },
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Error in fetching the data ${error}`);
      });
    ....
    ....
    ....
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
     ....
     ....
     ....
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainContent;
```

Comment: from where `customerData ` is coming?

Comment: 404 is not found error. means there should something wrong with your url

Comment: try console log your url and see what comes up

Comment: @ShubhamVerma: I'm getting ```customerData``` from a get request. I tried logging the ```customerData``` and I'm seeing the expected value. And I'm passing the value as props and in both cases, I'm seeing output when tried console log.

Comment: @TouseefAhmad: Yeah problem is with the URL because only ```type``` is getting passed into the URL. I'm getting the URL while logging in console.

Comment: If I try to hard code the value of ```customerData```, request is working.

Comment: Can you show the entire file with this code? There seems to be a problem with the scope of this variable.

Comment: @DehandeCroos: Oh okay

Comment: @DehandeCroos: Please check!

Comment: Not the answer but they way you understood context is wrong btw. Luckily your context value is an array so array destructors work here.
 `const theValueInContext = useContext(CustomerContext);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `options` variable get from the context and If this variable is get from the async function, you need to listen changes on this variable by adding this variable into the useEffect dependency array.

Your version did not work because you were calling fetchData function only one time (after the initial render).

```
  const fetchData = (customerData) => {
    ...
  }  

   useEffect(() => {
      if(options) {
       const hostNames = [];
       options.map((name, index) => {
       hostNames.push(name.customer.customHostName);
       });
        const customerData = hostNames[0];

        fetchData(customerData);
      } 
     }, [options]);
```

Comment: Last edited version should work if the options really comes as you expected

Comment: yes, Thats working for me. Can you update the answer showing a brief explanation, please?